# Fade in an image when the user hovers over a div

Tags: jquery, css

I have a few divs in a list and for each one I'm trying to get `.cat-icon` (image) to fade in smoothly when the user hovers over the parent div. Then once the mouse exits the `div`, the image should fade out smoothly. I'm having a bit of trouble and was hoping for some guidance.

https://jsfiddle.net/srqvafp3/1/

HTML

```
<section class="highlights">
  <article>
    <a href="/" class="image-link">
      <img width="351" height="185" src="http://i.imgur.com/f5h7bJo.jpg" class="image appear">
      <img class="cat-icon appear" width="60" height="60" src="http://i.imgur.com/imG6TE2.png"> 
    </a>
   </article>
</section>
```

JS

```
jQuery('.highlights article').on('mouseenter', '.highlights .image-link img.cat-icon', function(){
    jQuery(this).addClass('cat-icon-hover');
}).on('mouseleave', '.highlights .image-link img', function(){
    jQuery(this).removeClass('cat-icon-hover');
});
```

CSS

```
.highlights {
    position: relative;
}

.highlights article {
    position: relative;
}

.highlights .image-link {
    min-height: 42px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.highlights .image-link img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.highlights .image-link img.cat-icon {
    left: 50%;
    margin: -30px 0 0 -30px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 60px !important;
}

.highlights .image-link img:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.appear {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: what kind of trouble? i see its working, can you give the exact mean of `trouble` you tell.

Comment: simply use jQuery's  `fadeIn` and `fadeOut;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the below instead of your javascript.

```
$( ".highlights article" ).hover(
  function() {
    // Fade cat icon in on hover, at 200ms to opacity 1
    $(this).find('.cat-icon').fadeTo(200, 1);
  }, function() {
    // Fade cat icon out when hover leaves, at 200ms to opacity 0
    $(this).find('.cat-icon').fadeTo(200, 0);
  }
);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/srqvafp3/5/)

Comment: Thank you. This works; however, I have several of these articles and when I hover over one, they all fade out and show the icon.

Comment: @J82 try now, it should work but I'm on my phone so can't test.

Comment: Thanks it works. Just wondering if you knew of a more mobile friendly solution. For example, when I tap an article, the icon doesn't show up, but it takes me to the article. Then, when I swipe left to go back a screen, the icon shows up and stays there. Anyway, thanks again and I gave you the check.

Comment: Are the articles links? Do you not want them linking somewhere when someone clicks them?

Answer (score 0):

The class you are adding and removing on hover ("cat-icon-hover") is not in your CSS -?

`.jQuery(this).addClass('cat-icon-hover');`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$(this).toggleClass('cat-icon-hover');`